# Simulation of a particle and chemical molecule

Tags: computational-chemistry, nanotechnology

I am currently studying the basics of simulation and want to try out some experiments. It is a known fact that gold nanoparticles can bind to chemical groups which contains [thiol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thiol) (R–SH group). I want to simulate the binding of a thiol group to a gold nanoparticle. How can I do this? Where do I have to start? Which software can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Density Functional Theory is worth investigating if you're looking for a fairly efficient way of investigating these interactions at an electronic level. The term 'nanoparticle' is wonderfully vague as it encompasses two to three orders of size magnitude - the size of the nanoparticle will inform the specific choice of method:

Small (as in, only a couple of atoms) nanoparticles are amenable to computation with atom-centered basis sets in programs such as [Gaussian](http://www.gaussian.com/), [ADF](http://scm.com/), [ORCA](http://www.thch.uni-bonn.de/tc/orca/), [GAMESS](http://classic.chem.msu.su/gran/gamess/index.html) and so on. The latter two may be acquired free for academic use. If your particle/ligand complex is highly symmetric and/or you have supercomputer time you might be able to work with a moderately large particle. I recall a paper abstract where researchers did TDDFT on a 120 atom silver nanoparticle in ADF ([here it is!](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jp802707r)), aided by high symmetry.

Large systems, where it's a) computationally unreasonable to model the whole particle and b) to a first-order approximation the ligand-particle interaction can be treated as occurring on an infinite plane or edge, may be more amenable to periodic DFT using plane-wave basis sets (PW-DFT). There are many codes available, ranging from free to very expensive. Off the top of my head, [VASP](http://www.vasp.at/), [SIESTA](http://icmab.cat/leem/siesta/), [Quantum Espresso](http://www.quantum-espresso.org/), [Abinit](http://www.abinit.org/) and [CASTEP](http://accelrys.com/products/materials-studio/quantum-and-catalysis-software.html) are fairly popular.

There's also an atom-centered periodic franken-version of ADF called [ADF-BAND](http://www.scm.com/Products/BAND.html) which can model 1D to 3D periodic systems, which is worth mentioning. It is not particularly well documented, however.